# How to find the n value

Tags: complexity-theory

Consider two programs, A and B. Program A requires 1000 * n^2 (1000 multiplied by n to the power of 2) operations, and Program B requires 2^n (2 to the power of n) operations. For which values of n will Program A execute faster than Program B?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to compare both of these complexities is just to map them out as graphs.

[image: Graph showing both equations]

Just look where the lines intersect, that is 18.36. So if `n` is less than 18.36 then program a will execute faster.

For the exact answer, you can make the two equations equal each other then solve for `n` or just use WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000x%5E2%3D2%5Ex

Comment: is there any method to solve this whole problem and find n value?because I have to find the n value where Program A runs faster than program B?

Comment: Yes just make the 2 equations equal each other and solve for n. Or if you are allowed to use WolframAlpha, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000x%5E2%3D2%5Ex then under the real solutions section

Comment: can you plz send me the graph where the value of n for A is Less than B?

Answer (score 0):

For n > 18.3

Solve 1000 * n^2 = 2^n for the exact solution or use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000+*+n%5E2+%3D+2%5En)